# What does the error: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' mean during deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = ElementConstants.CreateDate, 
    Namespace = "http://api.facebook.com/1.0/",
    DataType = "date", Type = typeof(DateTime))]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

And if I try taking out the DataType in the attribute I get : {"The string '1233469624' is not a valid AllXsd value."}

Here is an example of one of the node values:

```
<created>1230437805</created>
```

I'm not sure how to setup the DateTime property here for this to be successfully deserialized.

Answer (score 11):

I've already answered this for you [a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523245/deserialization-error-the-xml-element-name-from-namespace-is-already-presen).

In your class, you need to do the translation:

```
static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
static long SerializeDateTime(DateTime value)
{
    return (long)((value - epoch).TotalSeconds);
}
static DateTime DeserializeDateTime(long value)
{
    return epoch.AddSeconds(value);
}

[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

[XmlElement("created"), Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public long CreateDateInt64 {
    get {return SerializeDateTime(CreateDate);}
    set {CreateDate = DeserializeDateTime(value);}
}
```

etc. The `CreateDateInt64` is the version that `XmlSerializer` uses - but when invoked, it does the translation and passes the value through to `CreateDate` (which is ignored by `XmlSerializer` due to the attribute).

This means you have a `DateTime CreateDate` on the class, and a number in the xml.

Comment: I was looking it up (he asked the same question 4 times, which didn't make it easy). And the questioner should already know I've given this linke!! I just wanted to prevent people spending their time looking too deep at something that has already been addressed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Had the same issue and was able to resolve using the method above.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a unix-formatted timestamp to me.  The Xml "date" datatype is very explicit in what the format should be:

> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff+timezone offset

For example:  `2009-02-09T10:01:23.3212345+06:00`

Comment: The OP can't control the data coming back from facebook... it is more a translation exercise. But yes, it is a unix-epoch timestamp.

Comment: Wouldn't xml have a `T` in the middle of that?